# Error when installing and importing echarts for angular 14.2.0

Tags: angular, echarts

I need to install echarts, but when i install it using npm with the commands:

npm install echarts -S
npm install ngx-echarts -S
npm install @types/echarts -D

the whole installation process goes well but as soon as i try to import it in my app.module.ts i get this error:
[Error on my screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kr7ex.png)

I have tried installing older versions of both echarts and ngx-echarts but does'nt seem to work either.

This is what my app.module.ts file looks like:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NgHttpLoaderModule } from 'ng-http-loader';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';
import { NgxEchartsModule } from 'ngx-echarts';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    SharedModule,
    NgxEchartsModule,
    NgHttpLoaderModule.forRoot(),
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Can you provide your app module code?

Comment: I edited the post to show it

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue with Angular 14.3.0, these 2 resolved it for me:

- Adding the import to app.module.ts as indicated by Joosep
- Installing ngx-echart 14.0.0 rather than the latest available

```
npm install ngx-echarts@14.0.0 --save
```

After that you might need to clear your node_modules folder and then run npm install to rebuild the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Documents explain it using as:

```
import { NgxEchartsModule } from 'ngx-echarts';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    NgxEchartsModule.forRoot({
      /**
       * This will import all modules from echarts.
       * If you only need custom modules,
       * please refer to [Custom Build] section.
       */
      echarts: () => import('echarts'), // or import('./path-to-my-custom-echarts')
    }),
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

https://xieziyu.github.io/ngx-echarts/#/welcome

Comment: After adding those things now I get the following errorError: node_modules/ngx-echarts/lib/ngx-echarts.directive.d.ts:93:18 - error TS2707: Generic type 'ɵɵDirectiveDeclaration' requires between 6 and 8 type arguments.

Comment: @SaulColin Did you ever find a solution to this issue?